# Почему приложение так сильно зумится?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Написано приложение на C# в UWP VS2015 Update 1. Во всех элементах ширина и высота подбирается auto. В родительском page элементе `Auto(1920)xAuto(1080)`, но на другой картинке вы можете увидеть что ui даже не помещается в экран с таким же разрешением. Создавал новый проект, добавлял SplitView но он всё равно получается увеличенный.
[image: Это как должно быть]
[image: Это как получается]

Как видите, все элементы увеличиваются, и просто не влезают в экран.

[Вот](http://pastebin.com/7kuV6sDW) ссылка с кодом XAML.

Comment: У вас у SplitView заданы абсолютные Margin, оно мешает ресайзить содержимое под размеры экрана и наоборот. Margin в WPF и UWP нужен больше для отступов в пару десятков пикселей, чтобы между элементами было расстояние хоть какое то.

Comment: `Margin="0,0,1130,0"`. Неудивительно, что неправильно зумится. Никогда не пытайтесь располагать элементы маргинами: это всё равно что в Ворде центрировать текст пробелами. Освойте layout management, всё будет получаться правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что на одном `SplitView` указано

```
Margin="0,0,1130,0"
```

а на втором

```
Margin="-50,0,-1130,0"
```

Если не использовать абсолютные отступы (`Margin`ы), то проблема решится.